# rowid is changing autometically in pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rowid

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROMOLOG1 AS
CURSOR rule IS SELECT * FROM business_rules; --this table had where conditions to use
TYPE r_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
ruleMatch r_cursor;
row_id VARCHAR2(20);
query_test VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN
  FOR a IN rule LOOP
    IF a.rule_name != 'Rule1' THEN
      OPEN rulematch FOR 'SELECT rowid FROM cold_promo_log_dup P WHERE EXISTS( SELECT   1 FROM cold_promo_log_dup C WHERE ' || a.condition || ' AND rowid < P.rowid)';
      dbms_output.put_line('matching completed for ' || a.rule_name);
      LOOP
         FETCH ruleMatch INTO row_id;
         EXIT WHEN rulematch%notfound;
         query_test := 'INSERT INTO cold_promo_log_duplicate SELECT * FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid = ''' || row_id ||'''' ;
         dbms_output.put_line(query_test);
         --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO cold_promo_log_duplicate SELECT * FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid = ''' || row_id || '''';
         INSERT INTO cold_promo_log_duplicate SELECT * FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid = row_id ;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid = ' || row_id;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END PROMOLOG1;
```

executing the above procedure in oracle throwing the following error:

```
    Connecting to the database dedupe_preprod.
    ORA-00904: "AAALJBABVAANSZDAAA": invalid identifier
    ORA-06512: at "DEDUPE.PROMOLOG1", line 23
    ORA-06512: at line 2
    matching completed for Rule2
    INSERT INTO cold_promo_log_duplicate SELECT * FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid =   'AAALJBABvAANsZDAAA'
    Process exited.
    Disconnecting from the database dedupe_preprod.
```

When i print the rowid it has few lower case letters(AAALJBABvAANsZDAAA), but the error shows all the  letters in uppercase(AAALJBABVAANSZDAAA). There is no rowid with uppercase in the DB, so the error invalid identifier is appearing.
        any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

firstly your row_id variable should be of type ROWID and not varchar2.

secondly this is the error:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM cold_promo_log_dup WHERE rowid = ' || row_id;
```

you didnt quote it (so its treated the rowid as a identifier ). but why are you running this in dynamic SQL?

Ps if you are going to leave this dynamic you should use a bind variable therefore not trash your shared pool and improve performance.

Comment: thanks its working now. i have modified my query with binding variable. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do your loop with the rowid. You do it so: you can delete the row, and insert it somewhere else. The best thing to do is to use a `DELETE ... RETURNING BULK COLLECT ...`, with this you won't need to use the rowid, and you can working with sets instead of using a for loop which will act line by line